# Installin ADT for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

When I tried to install the ADT Plugin for eclipse by adding the URL :
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse

I got the following error message:
Unable to read repository at:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml

Comment: What eclipse version are you using?

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#downloading) tells:

> In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:
>
> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
>
> Click OK
>
> Note: If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).

The URL looks right. Try using http instead of https as mentioned in the documentation.

Make sure that you have a recent version of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Eclipse Helios on ubuntu 11.04, If you have helios I'd recommend using Eclipse Galileo Latest version that worked for me. And yeah do try http:// instead of https://

Answer (score 1):

can you disable your antivirus firewall settings? 
Then try with https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

I have Windows 8 (64bit) and also got the same error. Right click and chose Run as Administrator and that worked. Didn't have to change to HTTP from HTTPS either.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem for eclipse juno (windows - 32 bits). I closed eclipse and then right click and chose `Run as Administrator`. After that, in `new software install` option, I wrote following URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and pressed enter. Setup contents were picked.

I hope it help someone. Cheers :)